# How to replace a character within a string

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to convert WText into its ASCII code and put it into a `TextBox`; `Numencrypt`. But I don't want to convert the spaces into ASCII code.

How do I replace the spaces with null?

Current code:

```
Dim withSpace As String = Numencrypt.Text
For h = 1 To lenText
    wASC = wASC & CStr(Asc(Mid$(WText, h, 1)))
Next h
Numencrypt.Text = wASC
Numencrypt2.Text = Numencrypt2.Replace(Numencrypt.Text, " ", "")
```

By the way, the `TextBox` `Numencrypt2` is the WText without a space inside it.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question but..what about first replacing the spaces in the input string and then _convert the string to the ASCII code_?

Comment: Could you provide some sample and expected output?

Comment: It seems you'd replacing the spaces too late. If you don't want to convert tye spaces into ASCII codes you gotta remove them before the loop. Try: `Dim withSpace As String = Numencrypt.Text.Replace(" ", "")` instead.

Comment: Also, please clarify if you want to convert spaces to an empty string or the null character. These 2 are not the same.

Comment: @Pikoh Thanks, it works now

Comment: Please note that `AscW` has nothing to do with ASCII. It uses the same character encoding as .NET strings: UTF-16. `Asc` also is not ASCII. It uses an encoding that varies across machines, users and time. Perhaps the problem here is the term "ASCII code". "Character code" is better but only because it introduces enough ambiguity to result in questions. *UTF-16 code unit* is possibly what's meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing whether or not you want the null character or empty string I did the following in a console app so I don't have your variables. I also used a string builder to make the string concatenation more performant.

```
Dim withSpaces = "This has some spaces in it!"
withSpaces = withSpaces.Replace(" "c, ControlChars.NullChar)
Dim wASC As New StringBuilder
For h = 1 To withSpaces.Length
    wASC.Append($"{AscW(Mid(withSpaces, h, 1))} ") ' Added a space so you can see the boundaries ascii code boundaries.
Next
Dim theResult = wASC.ToString()

Console.WriteLine(theResult)
```

You will find that if you use `ControlChars.NewLine` as I have, the place you had spaces will be represented by a zero. That position is completely ignored if you use `Replace(" ", "")`